# How is a probability computed when the end result requires multiple specific results across multiple trials?

Tags: probability

This question is inspired from a repeatable quest in an MMORPG. Defeating enemies in a certain area would give you a chance for a "Page" "drop". There were six different pages to acquire, and in order to complete the quest you needed one of each page. Assume each page is as equally likely as each of the others. Because the quest is repeatable, you may complete it each time you get a full set of pages.

My questions would be:
  What is the overall likelihood that a particular page drop will allow you to complete the quest again?

From zero of any page, and N=0, how would the chance that page drop N would allow for another complete set as N increases? Just from intuition, it will be impossible to complete the set from the first five page drops. (N=1 to N=5)

I think the chance of another complete set for very large N's might just simply approach 1/6, however how does a current surplus or deficit of a particular page affect the probability of completing the set?

Comment: This is an instance of the [coupon collector problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the answer.

Comment: Is the chance of completing a set on a specific N computable?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *computable*. The usual meaning of *computable* is that there is an algorithmn which computes the value in finite time (or, if the value is a real number, which computes an approximation for a given precision in finite time). Your probability is trivially computable in this sense. Tthere are only finitely many outcomes of $N$ picks from a set of size $M$, so you can simply enumerate them all. Then just compute the ratio of outcomes which yield each element at least once vs. the total number of outcomes...